# Color with the same hex code don‘t show the same color css

Tags: html, css

I have a website with icons, and I want to put the same color to the bg-color of a div and icons. For some reasons, it doesn’t seems to work.

Color that I want and that is a bg-color of a div (#f44336):

[image]

Color on icons (always #f44336):

[image]

Code (css):

```css
#play {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

/* a few css here */

#infos i {
  color: #f44336;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Share your HTML code for further understanding of the problem

Comment: may be it got overwritten with other defaulted style of icons. are you using bootstrap icons?

Comment: No I am using font awesome 5 and w3.css

Comment: Open you r browsers' dev tools inspect facility and look to see exactly who/where is setting/overriding the color settings. The code you have shown so far is not enough for us to see the problem.